# Codeigniter ActiveRecord: Where Clause with custom string

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, where-clause

I would like to search for the following string using CI active records.

> Click on the Event or Booking Code you would like to use.

My query is as follows:

```
$this->db->selet("id");
$this->db->where("column_name", "Click on the Event or Booking Code you would like to use.");
$this->db->from("table_name")
$ret = $this->db->get();
```

But it doesn't work since CI will escape the string and produce the select query as follows:

> SELECT `id` FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = 'Click on the Event or
>   `Booking Code you` `would` like to use.'

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$this->db->where("column_name = 'Click on the Event or  Booking Code you would like to use.'", NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: WHERE is not required in $this->db->where(). It should be something like:

$this->db->where("column_name ='Click on the Event or  Booking Code you would like to use.'", NULL,FALSE); 

I have already tried this method, but the problem is that it can be any string. Sometimes "You can't use this code". Then it won't work

Comment: $this->db->query() together with a $this->db->escape() will work in this case. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what the problem is. If you have to find values that may vary, use a string variable instead of plain text.

Comment: Your code will take out the use of escape() function. Assume that my custom string is something like "You can't use this code" (please note the apostrophe in the sentence). If I completely omit the db escape() function, it will end up with a MySQL error. 

Any how, I found the $this->db->query() along with a $this->db->escape() function working as expected.

Comment: what db engine do you use